# Persist processed records

Tags: c#, sqlite, persistence

I have a c# process that works against a queue using TPL to process in parallel. After handling each record, I want to establish a physical record of each record ID processed so that if the process fails or is interrupted, I can be sure to not process that record a second time. *It is imperative that records only be processed once.*

I have tried serializing record IDs to a simple text file AND to a Sqlite table. In both cases, the time to save these small record IDs (Guid's) takes 50% of the total process time for the record itself. I've even tried using an open Sqlite connection and a parameritized insert query to do inserts so I'm not opening/closing the database file and it's no better.

My question is, how can I maintain a list of Guid's (maybe 1000-2000 of them) in a persistent  way such that if my process dies, I'll have them saved so I can pick up where I left off? I'm willing to try anything as long as it's fast and will still be there if the server reboots or the process is killed.

Any ideas?

Comment: It can't take the same time to write to file and SqlLite. Can you share your code? Writing to file is very fast when you do it correctly (with buffered stream). Also, you dont need to write it to TEXT file per se, can you share the code? Also, my logger emits 50,000 messages to disk (from testing harness) per second with 1-2% CPU to disk. Writing to disk is faster than any SQL (even SQLLite)

Comment: How about using SQL Server?

Comment: My first try was to open a file for appending, write one row and close it but the slow down was on all the threads waiting for access to that block of code. I think the open for appending, write, close cycle was too slow. Is there a faster way that will also ensure the buffer is flushed if the process dies?

Comment: Let's try another way, if I have a StreamReader open for append and I flush after each write, can I be reasonably sure that everything I've written will be on disk if the process dies? This seems to be the fastest way I've found.

Answer (score 0):

Anything that is persistent enough to survive a reboot will have to be written to disk sooner or later (preferably sooner).

This means that you have pretty much enumerated your choices already.

The next questions that you have to ask is what is the expense of verifying whether or not the record has already been processed AND what is the danger level of an end-user inadvertently removing the tracking mechanism.

If you just write the information to a text file, it should be a fast write, but a slow read (unless you cache the information) and the likelihood that a user will remove the file is fairly high.

If you use a database of any kind, the write should still be reasonably fast and the retrieval should be faster than that of the text file and the likelihood that a user will remove the storage mechanism is much lower.

Based on these factors, I would strongly recommend a database of some sort. I would model (or research) a couple of different databases for performance to see which provides the best bang for the buck, which should include cost of implementation, deployment, and maintenance.